# Run Multiple Docker Images from One Bash script

Tags: ios, bash, macos, docker, terminal

I have a bash file that runs my apps docker image using `docker run -it --network test_network -p 8000:8000 testApp` but I also need to run my mysql image using `docker run -it --network test_network -p 3308:3308 mysql/mysql-server`

Normally I open a separate terminal window manually to run each one but I'm trying to edit my bash script so that it can do both for me. Not sure how though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run both in the detached mode. That will not block the script and allow you to run both together. For that, you need to use the `-d` or `--detach` flag.

> docker run --detach -it --network test_network -p 8000:8000 testApp
>
> docker run --detach -it --network test_network -p 3308:3308
>   mysql/mysql-server

Edit:
While the approach mentioned above works, it is better to use docker compose to run multiple containers.